# Hook on Windows Installer messages

Tags: c#, windows-installer, pinvoke

I wonder if there is any win32 API regarding the user install software on his machine ?

Is there is any event the windows fire when a user start to install software ?

I need to write an application that listen to this event and cancel the operation for some software.

Comment: Windows Group Policy can restrict things like this.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that malware does. As Daniel says, use policy and standard security features to control what is installed.

Comment: In same cases there is no Active Directory to control this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an app to disable installs based on MSI setups. See DisableMsi policy:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369784(v=vs.85).aspx

Setups built with other tools (that build non-MSI setups) can't really be detected because they're just applications that do things to the system, just like any other application, so there isn't really a way to stop them.